# How to calculate percentage of size change for window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, resize

I'm trying to calculate the percentage that the browser was resized but I can't seem to capture the size of the window before the resize began and then the size after it finishes.

```
$(function () {
    var originalHeight = $(window).height();
    $(window).resize(function (e) {
        var newHeight = $(window).height();
        var percentageChange = newHeight / originalHeight;
        $('body').html('old: ' + originalHeight + ' | new: ' + newHeight);
        originalHeight = newHeight;
    });
});
```

The two numbers (originalHeight and newHeight) always match for some reason. Is there something I can to to simulate two additional events such as `beginResize` or `endResize`? If I could do that then I could do this:

```
$(function () {
    var originalHeight;
    $(window).beginResize(function () {
        originalHeight = $(window).height();
    });
    $(window).endResize(function () {
        var newHeight = $(window).height();
        var percentageChange = newHeight / originalHeight;
        alert(percentageChange);
});
```

Any ideas?

### Update:

I was able to duplicate this locally in a blank environment, but not on jsfiddle. I can only conclude that the iframe environment on jsfiddle is interfering.

When I execute the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Isolate</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var originalHeight = $(window).height();
            $(window).resize(function (e) {
                var newHeight = $(window).height();
                var percentageChange = newHeight / originalHeight;
                $('body').append('old: ' + originalHeight + ' | new: ' + newHeight + ' | percentage: ' + percentageChange + '<br />');
                originalHeight = newHeight;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following results:

```
old: 417 | new: 418 | percentage: 1.0023980815347722
old: 418 | new: 418 | percentage: 1
old: 418 | new: 419 | percentage: 1.0023923444976077
old: 419 | new: 419 | percentage: 1
old: 419 | new: 420 | percentage: 1.0023866348448687
old: 420 | new: 420 | percentage: 1
old: 420 | new: 422 | percentage: 1.0047619047619047
old: 422 | new: 422 | percentage: 1
old: 422 | new: 423 | percentage: 1.0023696682464456
old: 423 | new: 423 | percentage: 1
```

It seems that the resize event is running twice for every resize. First time it detects a difference between original and new, but second time the values are the same because the first run updates originalHeight to the newHeight.

You can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RzE3/3/) that this double event run problem does not occur. Each entry shows different values for old and new.

Comment: The new height changes for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/8RzE3/.

Comment: Hmmm, you are correct. I will attempt to isolate any variables specific to my app.

Comment: Okay so I started a blank page on my local machine and I'm able to duplicate this issue using the same code from your fiddle. See my update.

Comment: Yep, definitely because of the iframe on jsfiddle. If you go straight to [the src link for the iframe](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8RzE3/2/show/) you can see the values are the same.

Comment: Can't reproduce this behavior, running FF 13.0.1 (32bit) on Win7x64 (new height differs from old one). But apparently maximizing the window in Windows will first move the window, then resize the window, and then trigger resize another time since the position of the UI elements has changed.

Comment: Try it in the latest Chrome. I think the browser is firing it twice. Maybe it's browser specific.

Comment: @Alex Ford: You're correct. For the record, if you put a breakpoint inside the resize handler, and then maximize the window the event is indeed fired twice: first correctly with a new value, and then again with that same new value (so that the values displayed are equal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is entirely browser specific. It occurs in neither Opera, Firefox nor IE, but in Chrome.

In order to avoid this behavior you can simply check whether the last update has happened in a certain interval (for example the last 100ms) ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8RzE3/6/), tested in all common browsers):

```
$(function () {
    var originalHeight = $(window).height();
    var originalHeightTime = new Date();
    $(window).resize(function (e) {
        var newTime = new Date();
        if (newTime - originalHeightTime < 100)
            return;
        var newHeight = $(window).height();
        var percentageChange = newHeight / originalHeight;
        $('body').html('old: ' + originalHeight + ' | new: ' + newHeight + ' | percentage: ' + percentageChange);
        originalHeight = newHeight;
        originalHeightTime = newTime;
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting. I came up with an almost identical solution right before I read your answer, except I used setTimeout to achieve the same effect. http://fiddle.jshell.net/8RzE3/7/